# How can I remove extraneous information from lines in a log file?

Tags: perl

`read_data: read failure for 4 bytes to client 158.136.150.108. Error = Connection reset by peer`

In the line above, I want to use the `s///` operator to remove all the text in the line after "read_data:".

Comment: Do you expect to write the entire program by asking bits and pieces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$subject =~ s/(?<=^read_data:).*//;
```

This simple perl regex will do the trick.

Working example : http://ideone.com/zhGi5

Comment: `/g` doesn't make much any sense. There's only one spot that could possibly match. If your concerned with efficiency, this isn't that efficient. With the /g, it needs to every every position, period. Without the /g, it needs to try to match at 10 different positions before succeeding on lines that match, and at every position on lines that don't match. My solution only checks at one position in both cases.

Comment: @ikegami Removed g. Was left over from previous regex. :). As for the new line the OP states that there is **NO** new line. "remove all the text in the **line** after "read_data:"."

Comment: @FailedDev, First, the OP doesn't say there is no newline. Lines usually end with newlines, so if anything, the OP implies there is one. If you really want to remove the rest of the line, use `/s`. I think it's better to leave the newline if there is one, though, as your code currently does.

Comment: @ikegami I think it's pointless to argue over this. Both solutions are fine.

Comment: @FailedDev, Argue? I said I like your solution!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

```
$str =~ s/^read_data\K:.*//;
```

Fast (by virtue of not using captures) and simple. It even preserves the newline if there is one. If you want to remove any trailing newline, use the following instead:

```
$str =~ s/^read_data\K:.*//s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my ($event) = ($line =~ /^(read_data):/);
    next unless defined $event;
    print "$event\n";
}

__DATA__
read_data: read failure for 4 bytes to client 158.136.150.108. Error = Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to use the regex replace? i.e. "s" function?

Comment: @FailedDev: `s///` is not a function, it is an operator. And, why does it matter that the OP wanted to use the substitution operator? Sometimes, there are alternative ways of doing things that are more concise and do not require firing up `perldoc perlreref`.

Comment: Trust me, I know what it is. I just used the wording of the OP.

Comment: That prints a warning and a blank line for every line that doesn't match /^read_data:/. I think you want `my $fixed_line = $line =~ /^read_data:/ ? 'read_data' : $line;`.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, What are called functions in the documentation (perlfunc) are actually operators anyway. perlop calls them "list operators". Have a peek at `perl -MO=Concise -e'sub f {} f(); localtime();'` and notice how `localtime` doesn't result in an `entersub` op.

Comment: @ikegami However, referring to `readline` as a function and `<FH>` as an operator can still be useful regardless of implementation details. As for the processing, it would have been better for the OP to post a snippet of the log file and point out what he wants to keep/remove so that a complete solution could be given.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, Yes, using two names is useful. Just pointing out your nit pick wasn't entirely correct.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, The OP didn't ask to remove other lines at all. He definitely didn't ask for warnings and blank lines. You really think he wants a whole bunch of "read_data" and nothing else? That's the only time your program would be useful.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you. I post self contained programs that can be copied and pasted and run with no other effort. It is up to the OP to integrate whatever he/she is doing.